# cout does not print the return value from a function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am doing a problem where I have to pass an array through a function, and it returns the minimum integer in the range of indexes the user inputs. The problem is `cout` is not displaying the return value of the function that is being called:

[image]

Could anyone show me what is wrong?

```
#include <iostream>;
#include <array>;
using namespace std;

int minInARange (int array[], int lowIndex, int highIndex);

int main()
{
    int myArray[15];

    for (int i = 0; i <15; i++)
    {
        myArray[i] = 15 + rand() % (55 - 15 + 1);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        cout << myArray[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;

    int lowIndex = 0;
    int highIndex = 0;

    cout << "Enter in a low index of the array (0-14): " << endl;
    cin >> lowIndex;
    cout << "Enter in a higher index of the array (0-14): " << endl;
    cin >> highIndex;

    cout << "The lowest number in the range of array indices is: ";
    cout << minInARange(myArray, lowIndex, highIndex) << endl;

    return 0;
}

int minInARange (int array[], int lowIndex, int highIndex)
{
    int lowestNum = array[lowIndex];
    for (int i = 0; i < highIndex - lowIndex; i++)
    {
        if (array[i] < lowestNum)
        {
            lowestNum = array[i];
        }
    }
    return lowestNum;
}
```

Comment: Post your output instead of screenshots and remove the `;` in the first two lines

Comment: What happens if lowIndex is not 0? i is always set to 0 first.

Comment: Yeah i had it set as lowIndex at first but I changed it to 0. I don't know what was going through my head haha. I took out the semi colons, but I am still not getting an output for my function

Comment: What is your question? What part are you having difficulty with?

Comment: My question is why my cout is not displaying my lowest integer from the function?

Comment: Is it the case that `highIndex >= lowIndex`? You should probably put a check in `minInARange` to ensure it.

Comment: I suggest that you get a piece of paper and a pencil and work through your code by hand. Figure out what the value of each variable should be as each line of code executes. Then use a debugger to verify that what you expect is what actually happens.

Comment: Works for me. http://ideone.com/ja3VKt

Answer (score -1):

```
int minInARange (int array[], int lowIndex, int highIndex) {
   cout << "lo:" << lowIndex << " hi:" << highIndex << endl;
   for (int i=lowIndex; i<highIndex; i++) //maybe <=, depends what you want
     cout << "Tock:" << i << endl;
     ....
}
```

Comment: Thanks, my output still won't show my lowestNum value though?

Comment: Try my new version. Then you'll probably see the problem.